# URL parameters ending with '#'

Tags: php, html, url, parameters

What is the purpose of using `#` at the end of a URL with parameters ?

i.e. `https://www.example.com/mypage?name=George&profession=Engineer#`

I have noticed that in my browser if my URL is like this:

`https://www.example.com/mypage?name=George&profession=Engineer` (without `#`)

and I hit `Enter` then I'm redirected.

But if my URL ends with `#` and I hit enter, nothing happens.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: The stuff after `#` is called a fragment.  It's not sent to the server as part of the URL.  The purpose is for anchor tags like `<a id="foo"` then when you put `#foo` the page will scroll to that item (traditionally).  It's sometimes used for AJAX (state) or one page navigation these days.

Comment: `#` are usually used as page anchors. If there is a `<a id="paragraph2">`, and you go to `example.com/mypage#paragraph2`, it will jump you down to that paragraph.

Comment: @Alcaeus  FYI, this is something you easily could have searched yourself.  Bear in mind for the future that such questions are often downvoted.

Comment: The use of `<a>` elements to be the target of fragment ids is a hangover from HTML 3.2. Since HTML 4 you can target **any** element.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix: "fragment identifier", not "fragment"

Comment: @Patrick Q, if you read what google and ad words say about these kind of urls you could see that a simple search query doesn't amswer my question. The question was asked to receive more valid information about "What finally is the purpose of using fragments"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#` indicates the start of the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This **follows** the query string and is not part of it.

It causes the browser to navigate to the element with the matching ID in the page the previous sections of the URL refer to.

```
http://example.com/foo/?bar=123#baz
```

… will link to the element with `id="baz` (such as `<section id="baz">...</section>`) in `http://example.com/foo/?bar=123`

---

The page doesn't reload when you just add a `#` and press enter because the browser knows it already has the page loaded and will just scroll to the matching id (or the top of the page in this case because there is no matching id).